# How to programmatically add errors for a Monodevelop Project?

Tags: monodevelop, add-in

I'm writing an [addin](http://monoaddins.codeplex.com/documentation) for [monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) and I want to add programmatically parsing errors **outside of a compilation process**.

In my addin, when I parse the file I get a list of errors that are not related to a compilation process and that I would like to add in the error output.

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to create a `Task` like this:

```
TaskService.Errors.Add (new Task ("/path/to/file.xx, "Error message ", 10, 30, TaskSeverity.Error));
```